# Beginner's guide to ElasticSearch

Tags: search, full-text-search, elasticsearch

There hasn't been any books about ElasticSearch (that I know of), and http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/ seems to contain only references.

Any good beginner's guide or tutorials, perhaps by examples, to recommend, especially in terms of the different mapping and indexing strategies?

Comment: For any future hunters, a book has now been published:
http://www.amazon.com/ElasticSearch-Server-ebook/dp/B00BAOC2KQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1361450832&sr=8-1&keywords=elasticsearch

Comment: You might want to checkout the free book I'm writing at http://exploringelasticsearch.com . The focus is on building a solid conceptual foundation anchored in real world examples.

Comment: I have found so many useful stuff here because of this question. How on earth it's not constructive! Thanks for asking and thanks anyone to keep updating their answers.

Comment: @AndrewCholakian Could you run the examples from the book with Elastic Hammer? To me trying to run the examples from Figure 2.4 returns conn errored, although my Elastic Search is running and I loaded the movie database. I wonder what I am doing wrong, did it work for you?

Comment: If a question has over a hundred upvotes, it certainly is constructive. Why is one dorkenstein permitted to block everyone else from contributing?!

Comment: Always great too come to SO to find an incredibly useful question marked as otherwise

Comment: And yet another book that's just been published by Manning: [Elasticsearch in Action](http://manning.com/hinman)

Comment: Lots of these resources may be outdated as of 2021... So I've released my own handbook at https://elasticsearchbook.com!

Answer (score 283, accepted):

**Edit (April 2015):**

As many have noticed, my old blog is now defunct.  Most of my articles were transferred over to the Elastic blog, and can be found by filtering on my name:  https://www.elastic.co/blog/author/zachary-tong

To be perfectly honest, the best source of beginner knowledge is now [Elasticsearch - The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/index.html) written by myself and Clinton Gormley.

It assumes zero search engine knowledge and explains information retrieval first principals in context of Elasticsearch.  While the reference docs are all about finding the precise parameter you need, the Guide is a narrative that discusses problems in search and how to solve them.

Best of all, the book is OSS and free (unless you want to buy a paper copy, in which case O'Reilly will happily sell you one :) )

**Edit (August 2013):**

Many of my articles have been migrated over to the [official Elasticsearch blog](http://elasticsearch.org/blog/), as well as new articles that have not been published on my personal site.

**Original post:**

I've also been frustrated with learning ElasticSearch, having no Lucene/Solr experience.  I've been slowly documenting things I've learned at my blog, and have four tutorials written so far:

So I don't have to keep editing, [all future tutorials on my blog can be found under this category link.](http://euphonious-intuition.com/category/elasticsearch/)

And these are some links that I have bookmarked, because they have been incredibly helpful in one way or another:

- [Thinking through and debugging problems with your query](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/I-am-tired-of-continuously-trying-to-override-the-default-analyzer-and-tokanizer-settings-tp3350150p3354293.html)
- [Another example of complicated mapping (ngram, synonyms, phonemes)](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/help-needed-with-the-query-tp3177477p3178856.html)
- [Searching parts of a word](http://blog.avisi.nl/2012/02/22/searching-parts-of-words-with-elasticsearch/)
- [Fun with ElasticSearch's children and nested documents](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/)

Comment: Thanks for writing and sharing about your blog with the tutorials. I've gone through some of them and I find them very well written. Some of these, esp the one on mapping, ought to be linked from the main ES site. Really appreciate your collection of links as well.

Comment: This is also helpful for pure code samples:
https://github.com/kimchy/talks/blob/master/2011/wsnparis/

By the way, the Poster addin for firefox is pretty helpful for playing around with and RestAPI such as ElasticSearch.

Comment: I'm actually writing a book on elasticsearch which is available here: http://exploring-elasticsearch.com/ . It's still in draft form, but may be useful

Comment: looks like http://euphonious-intuition.com is down

Comment: @alex it is, sorry...having some hosting troubles.  I'll get it back online soon!

Comment: seems euphonious-intuition.com is still down :(

Comment: The links above are expired!

Comment: @Zach The links given are not available now .Its goddady default page

Comment: For those still searching for a concise book: I've put together and released a collection of "Use Case vs. Approach" guides at https://elasticsearchbook.com!

Answer (score 14):

You can Learn the overview using this link

http://spinscale.github.com/elasticsearch/2012-03-jugm.html#/1

Comment: Personally I recommend this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxFqE5usuh0 @uzyn

Comment: both links are broken

Answer (score 13):

I found Elastic Search one of the hardest things I've had to learn, I hadn't used Lucene before and I found the documentation to be quite hard to follow.

These are the things that I wish I'd known before I started learning it:

**Configuration and setup**

I configured ELS to run on 3 VM' using Centos, Mint and Ubuntu. Centos was by far the best choice of the three.

[I followed this guide](http://xenforo.com/community/threads/how-to-basic-elasticsearch-installation-debian-ubuntu.26163/) to help me set it up (it worked fine on all three distros)

**Index and types**

One Index can contain many types, it's by using types that you can achieve a good degree of separation of data that belongs within the same index.

**PHP**

I use PHP as a front end and [used this wrapper](https://github.com/nervetattoo/elasticsearch) to integrate my ELS installation into my scripts.

**Other resources**

The presentation in the other answer to your question is really good, go through it and learn the DSL Query syntax, once setup this is where the real power of ELS comes into its own.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very useful pointers. I've been looking for good pointers like these when I first asked the question due to the lacking of a proper tutorial-like guide for ES.

Comment: While you suggested https://github.com/nervetattoo/elasticsearch, I have been following https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica for months and seen good followings and activities around Elastica. You have any comments on the 2 wrappers, if you have checked out both?

Comment: Yeah actually, the Elastica wrapper is really good as well, it is far more powerful than the repo I've been using but with more power comes greater complexity that at the time I didnt want as Elastic Search itself was proving enough of a challenge :)

Answer (score 13):

If you're new to elasticsearch and the “information retrieval” / “fulltext search” in general, my advice would be to check these resources first, before trying out tutorials on specific features:

- The [*Your Data, Your Search, ElasticSearch*](http://www.slideshare.net/karmi/your-data-your-search-elasticsearch-euruko-2011) presentation from EURUKO 2011
- The [*ElasticSearch - A Distributed Search Engine*](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ElasticSearch) talk by Shay Bannon together with [accompanying scripts](https://github.com/kimchy/talks/tree/master/2011/wsnparis)
- The [*Lucene in Action*](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/) book (at least the general chapters on the indexing, analysis, tokenization, and constructing queries)