# Is ElasticSearch: The Definitive Guide still relevant?

Tags: elasticsearch

Just having some free time at the moment and looking into a deep dive into ElasticSearch to understand how it works and its area of applications. Came across ElasticSearch: The Definitive Guide online, read through the "foreword" & "how to read sections", realised that it's for ElasticSearch v2, although the concepts section should be as great.

For people who have came across both the book and are still very updated with the latest releases of ElasticSearch, any particular sections should I view along with the latest reference/other resources?

Side note: are there any other fun projects/beginner guides to get started on as well? (Other than anything from here: [Beginner's guide to ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593035/beginners-guide-to-elasticsearch))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general concepts still hold, but details have been changing and the query syntax has changed quite a bit. It's still a good place to get started.

In general all the effort (at the moment) goes into the regular documentation. So once you've familiarized yourself with the concepts, I'd dive into the docs of whatever you are trying to do. That should give you a good approach to getting started and then going to production.

Comment: If that solved your question, please mark it as the correct answer.